# Can somebody please tell me which sentence is correct and why?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

"**I am the one who is ready**" vs "**I am the one who am ready**".
Which sentence  is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

The referent  of ‘who’ in the sentences is the third person pronoun ‘one’ which requires third person singular form of be.

Comment: Can you kindly provide more detail clarity?  Which sentence of the two is the proper grammar. Thanks⁰

Comment: An authoritative reference would really improve this answer.